# How to customize the output file location using grunt-sass

Tags: gruntjs

I currently have a custom location to which I want to output the generated css file from grunt-sass. In my GruntFile.js I have:

```
sass: {
  options: {
    includePaths: ['bower_components/foundation/scss']
  },
  dist: {
    options: {
      outputStyle: 'compressed'
    },
    files: {
      'dist/assets/css/app.css': 'src/assets/scss/app.scss'
    }        
  }
}
```

I want to replace 'dist/assets/css/app.css' with a custom location specified from command line. Is there any way to do this for grunt-sass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grunt provides applying command line parameters. Here is explanation: http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.option

In your case solution may looks like:

1. Declare variable somewhere at the top of Gruntfile.js:

   ```
   var myVariable = grunt.option('src')';

   grunt.initConfig({
   ...
   ```
2. In your `sass` task change:

   ```
   files: {
     'dist/assets/css/app.css': 'src/assets/scss/app.scss'
   }
   ```

   to

   ```
   files: [
     { src: ['src/assets/scss/app.scss'], dest: myVariable
   ]
   ```
3. And finally, in command line call:

   ```
   grunt sass --src='your/new/src'
   ```